# Spring Security RememberMe Not Working in Safari

Tags: spring, security, spring-mvc

I have successfully configured a Spring application with Spring Security and the Persistent RememberMe functionality. However, the following steps produce an error in Safari 7.1.2:

1. Signin with remember me (creation of token in database is confirmed).
2. Manually delete JSESSIONID cookie from browser to simulate session expiration.
3. Refresh browser.

The resulting error is:

> org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.CookieTheftException: Invalid remember-me token (Series/token) mismatch. Implies previous cookie theft attack.

Taking these exact same steps in FireFox 31.3.0 successfully logs the user in again as expected.

The following is the Java config for the application security:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
@ComponentScan(basePackages={"com.example.app.config"})
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

@Autowired
private DataSource dataSource;

@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

    auth.jdbcAuthentication()
        .dataSource(dataSource);

}

@Override
public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/new").access("hasRole('USER')")
        .antMatchers("/call/**").access("hasRole('USER')")
        .antMatchers("/contacts/**").access("hasRole('USER')")
        .antMatchers("/").access("hasRole('USER')")
        .antMatchers("/resources/css/**").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/resources/js/**").permitAll()
        .and()
            .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/signin")
            .loginProcessingUrl("/j_spring_security_check")
            .usernameParameter("username")
            .passwordParameter("password")
            .permitAll();

    http.rememberMe()
        .key("notasecret")
        .rememberMeServices(rememberMeServices())
        .userDetailsService(userDetailsService());
}

@Bean 
public JdbcDaoImpl userDetailsService() {
    JdbcDaoImpl userDetailsService = new JdbcDaoImpl();
    userDetailsService.setDataSource(dataSource);
    return userDetailsService;
}

@Bean
public PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices rememberMeServices() {
    PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices services = new PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices("notasecret", userDetailsService(), tokenRepository());
    services.setTokenValiditySeconds(43200);
    return services;
}

@Bean
public JdbcTokenRepositoryImpl tokenRepository() {
    JdbcTokenRepositoryImpl repository = new JdbcTokenRepositoryImpl();
    repository.setDataSource(dataSource);
    return repository;
}
```

Here is what happens in the debug trace for Safari:

```
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - / at position 1 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter'
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - / at position 2 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository - No HttpSession currently exists
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository - No SecurityContext was available from the HttpSession: null. A new one will be created.
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - / at position 3 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'HeaderWriterFilter'
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter - Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match the requestMatcher org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter$SecureRequestMatcher@69d3d174
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - / at position 4 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'CsrfFilter'
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - / at position 5 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter'
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher - Request 'GET /' doesn't match 'POST /logout
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - / at position 6 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter'
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher - Request 'GET /' doesn't match 'POST /j_spring_security_check
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - / at position 7 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RequestCacheAwareFilter'
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - / at position 8 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter'
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - / at position 9 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RememberMeAuthenticationFilter'
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices - Remember-me cookie detected
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices - Cancelling cookie
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository - SecurityContext is empty or contents are anonymous - context will not be stored in HttpSession.
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter - SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
Jan 27, 2015 11:54:17 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [appServlet] in context with path [/ocl] threw exception
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.CookieTheftException: Invalid remember-me token (Series/token) mismatch. Implies previous cookie theft attack.
```

My theory is that the point in the log stating "Cancelling cookie" is the problem. However, I do not know why this is happening.

Please let me know if anyone has run into this issue or if there is something wrong or missing with the above configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I started with a bare bones security-only application to remove all other complexities and was able to get the remember me functionality to work. I took a peak at the respective POM.xml files between my test application and main application and removed the following dependency from the application where remember me wasn't working:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.5.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

This must have been conflicting with `spring-security-core` because everything worked fine after I removed the dependency.